Ctrl + Click go to JavaScript definition not working PhpStorm 2024
After updating PhpStorm to 2024.1 it's no longer possible to go to the declaration of a JavaScript function by Ctrl + Click

Broader context in the file.

Why do you tag PHP?

does it happen in plain .html file. or in PHP, or? Can you reproduce the issue in a new project?

The problem appears with laravel configuration and with @extends('layouts.base')

I suggest to raise an issue on jetbrains or amend an already existing bug.

I fixed the issue by going back to the 2023.3.6 version
